# IDE para Python que tenha modelagem de GUI

Tags: python, ide, gui

Queria saber se existe um IDE para programar em Python que forneça um ferramenta para montar um GUI mais facilmente, de prefêrencia que tenha versões para Linux e Windows.

Comment: Aqui tem algumas: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende do que você quer. O IDE [Anjuta](http://anjuta.org/) tem uma boa integração com o [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) que é uma das ferramentas mais populares para fazer o design de UIs com [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/).

Mas no mundo Python você não necessariamente precisa ficar preso a uma ferramenta. Eu geralmente uso o [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) para codificar e algo como o [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/), [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/ide/) ou [wxFormBuilder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/) para desenhar as telas. A escolha por uma ferramenta ou outra vai depender do [*widget toolkit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits) utilizado no projeto.